# jQuery onchange and if condition

Tags: jquery

Need some help in using this jquery. I'm trying to show a div id in certain conditions if they are met.

I have 2 dropdown box which is Remote and Test and both have values of Yes and No.

So I need to show Text 1 if both Remote and Test have No value.

Text 2 if Remote is Yes and Test is No.

Text 3 if Remote is No and Test is Yes.

Text 4 if Remote is Yes and Test is Yes.

If someone could help me out with the script, it will be much appreciated.

I've managed to make it work with only one condition but seems like having a problem with multiple conditions.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Test </title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

 $("#remote,#test").on("change", function(){
    if( $(#remote).val() == "No" && $(#test).val() == "No" ){
      $("#show1").show();
      $("#show2").hide();
      $("#show3").hide();
      $("#show4").hide();
    } else if ( $(#remote).val() == "Yes" && $(#test).val() == "No" ){
      $("#show1").hide();
      $("#show2").show();
      $("#show3").hide();
      $("#show4").hide();
    } else if ( $(#remote).val() == "No" && $(#test).val() == "Yes" ){
      $("#show1").hide();
      $("#show2").hide();
      $("#show3").show();
      $("#show4").hide();
    } else if ( $(#remote).val() == "Yes" && $(#test).val() == "Yes" ){
      $("#show1").hide();
      $("#show2").hide();
      $("#show3").hide();
      $("#show4").show();
    } 
        });

</script>
</head>

<body>

<span>Remote</span>
<select id="remote" name="Remote" "value="" >
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select> <br>

<span>Test</span>
<select id="test" name="Test" "value="" >
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select> <br> <br>

<div id="show1">
Text 1
</div>

<div id="show2" style="display: none">
Text 2
</div>

<div id="show3" style="display: none">
Text 3
</div>

<div id="show4" style="display: none">
Text 4
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Missing lots of quotes on selectors which will error out

Comment: @charlietfl I've tried checking on all the quotes and it seems like they are complete to me. Can you show me the right track?

Comment: `$(#remote)` should be `$("#remote")` ... same with `$(#test)`. Might be different in your working file but in question not

Comment: I've tried changing it to $("#remote") and $("test) but still not working.

Comment: That should be $("test") as well.

Comment: That would probably be `$("#test")`. Show enough html to make this a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select` if you only need *of/off* states (If you really don't have to...).
*We* invented a better UI for that purpose called **input checkbox**.

Having **two** checkboxes and all their premutations (**4** total) - all you need is:

#### Binary to integer conversion

> **Binary to integer table:**
>
> 00 = 0
>    01 = 1
>    10 = 2
>    11 = 3

The binary represents the two checkboxes states. We'll use the Integer as the Element Index.

- To get the **binary** string (`'00'`, `'01'` etc), concatenate the two checkboxes `checked` boolean property - converted to number using the Unary `+` (We'll use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) to achieve that to-string concatenation.)
- Having the binary strings now we need an **integer** that will represent the index of the element we want to target. We'll use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with Radix `2`
- To finally target a specific DOM Element by it's **index** in the jQuery-object collection we can use the [`.eq()` Method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
const $ckb = $('#remote, #test')
const $box = $('.box');

$ckb.on('change', function() {

  const bin = $ckb.get().reduce((str, el) => str += +el.checked, '');
  const idx = parseInt(bin, 2);
  $box.hide().eq(idx).show();

});
```

```css
.box~.box { display: none; }
.noYes        +span:after{content:'No';}
.noYes:checked+span:after{content:'Yes';}
```

```html
<label>
  Remote
  <input type="checkbox" class="noYes" id="remote" name="Remote">
  <span></span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Test
  <input type="checkbox" class="noYes" id="test" name="Test">
  <span></span>
</label>

<div id="boxes">
  <div class="box">00 = 0 Remote is No and Test is No.</div>
  <div class="box">01 = 1 Remote is No and Test is Yes.</div>
  <div class="box">10 = 2 Remote is Yes and Test is No.</div>
  <div class="box">11 = 3 Remote is Yes and Test is Yes.</div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```